# How to modify bash command to change permissions

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I have this bash command to modify all files and folders permissions inside a root folder:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

it work ok.
What i should do to to exclude some folders for change permissions inside the root folder(where the bash is executed).
For example, if i want to keep folder permission for folder "A" and folder "B"
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an example directory layout? before and after?

Comment: Sure. For exmaple i have a "Products" folder and inside some folders: "ProductA", "ProductB" , "ProductC" , etc. When i run the script all folders get 755. But i want to be able to exclude "ProductA" and "ProductC" to change permissions

Comment: so only the permission of directory in the root folder should be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude directories with `-prune` option:

```
find . -type d -name ProductA -prune -o -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

It tells: if file is a directory and has name `ProductA`, then do not descend into it (`-prune`), else (`-o` means or) if file is a directory, then execute the `chmod 755` on it.

`find` expressions are made of options, tests (can be false or true) and actions, separated by operators. When no action is given, then `-print` action is performed on all files for which the expression is true. `-exec` is an action, `-prune` is another. You can chain multiple actions with `-a` and `-o`. `expr1 -a expr2` will execute both actions, whereas `expr1 -o expr2` will execute `expr2` only if `expr1` evaluates to false.

So if you want to exclude multiple directories, you can write

```
find . -type d -name ProductA -prune -o -type d -name ProductC -prune -o -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type d -name ProductA -prune -o -type d -name ProductC -prune -o -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

or just:

```
find . -type d -name "Product[AC]" -prune -o -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type d -name "Product[AC]" -prune -o -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

and you can combine them too:

```
find . -type d -name "Product[AC]" -prune -o -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; -o -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

If you have a more complex directory structure, say you want to exclude `ProductA/data` but not `ProductB/data` nor `ProductA/images`, then you can use the `-path` test:

```
find . -path ./ProductA/src -prune -o -print
```

Comment: very good, thanks, but what should i do if i want to ignore all files inside the excluded folders. For example, lets say i want to exclude "ProductA"  and "ProductC" folders, but also ignore all their files.

Comment: Im talking about second line:  
     find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

Comment: Use this command: `find . -type d -name ProductA -prune -o -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`. It will go through files and directories recursively. If the directory named `ProductA` is found, then it will be _pruned_ from the search, meaning that all files that belong to ProductA directory will be excluded. So you will change permissions only to the other files. You can check found files by asking `find` to print them with `find . -type d -name ProductA -prune -o -type f -print`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

`find . -type d \(-name "*" ! -name "A" ! -name "B" \) -exec chmod 755 {}\;`

`find . -type d \(-name "*"` - lists all the directories in the current directories

`!-name "A" !-name "B"` - ignores directories with names A and B

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude multiple directories, e.g. `dirname1, dirname2` using `egrep -v` and then execute `chmod` using `xargs`.

```
find . -type d | egrep -v "(dirname1|dirname2)" | xargs chmod 755
```